# Update is not working when DML is outside the FOR LOOP

Tags: apex, class, wrapper-class

I am having issues when placing the UPDATE outside the For Loop, for some reason is only updating the last selected item in the wrap class, but if I placed it inside the loop it works perfectly. I know for sure that the DML should always be outside loops, so please can anybody tell if I am doing something wrong. I will appreciate any help.

```
public void CreatePlan() {
    Map<id,Outbound_Sales_Order__c> ToUpdate = new Map<id,Outbound_Sales_Order__c>();

    //here for loop to get values from wrap class 
    for (String row : selectedTasks) 
    {
        for(Outbound_Sales_Order__c p : [SELECT id  FROM Outbound_Sales_Order__c  WHERE  name =: row.substring(0,7)])
        {
            if(row.substring(21) == '1' ){ p.Bol_1__c = 'bol1';  }
            if(row.substring(21) == '2' ){ p.Bol_2__c = 'bol2';  }
            if(row.substring(21) == '3' ){ p.Bol_3__c = 'bol3';  }
            ToUpdate.put((id)p.get('id'),p);
        }
        // if I do the update here, it will work.
    }
    //update outsite for loop 
    UPDATE ToUpdate.values();
}
```

[image]

Comment: You still have your query in a for loop anti-pattern to remove also.

Comment: Minor point, but instead of using `(id)p.get('id')` you can just do `p.id` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the values of `ToUpdate` to another map at the end of each *inner For Loop* but within the *Outer For Loop* to prevent this problem from happening.

As located below:

```
    }
    // if I do the update here, it will work.
    // *** Add to a 2nd map here ***
}
```

**EDIT:**

It appears that what's happening is you're updating different fields in the same `Outbound_Sales_Order__c` during different iterations, so when you try to add them to your list, the duplicate Ids are causing a problem. Even if you add the lists of records from the inner loop to a map at the point above, you're still going to have an issue with trying to combine the records that have the same Id's.

Now, if you knew the precise field names that had been updated in each record, you could more easily do something at the end of each loop to combine records with the same Id. One way of doing that would be to map the field names during each iteration with the record Id. That would allow you to retrieve the existing record from the map (assuming the record Id is already contained in the map), assign the value from the updated field for the latest inner For Loop to the record, after which you'd put the revised record back into the map that contains all the field updates.

As an alternative, you could create a map of lists to use for collecting the records in the For Loops. This map would hold the records collected from each iteration through the inner loop and would look like this:

```
List<Outbound_Sales_Order__c> ToUpdate = new List<Outbound_Sales_Order__c>();
map<integer, list<Outbound_Sales_Order__c>>mapToUp = new map<integer, list<Outbound_Sales_Order__c>>;
integer i = 0;

for (String row : selectedTasks) 
{
    i=0;
    for(Outbound_Sales_Order__c p : [SELECT id  FROM Outbound_Sales_Order__c  WHERE  name =: row.substring(0,7)])
    {
        if(row.substring(21) == '1' ){ p.Bol_1__c = 'bol1';  }
        if(row.substring(21) == '2' ){ p.Bol_2__c = 'bol2';  }
        if(row.substring(21) == '3' ){ p.Bol_3__c = 'bol3';  }
        ToUpdate.add(p);
    }
    mapToUp.put(i,ToUpdate);
    ToUpdate.clear();
    i++;
} 

// now you'll need to retrieve the lists and update them one by one. 
// Alternatively, if you also create a map of the field names updated in each loop, 
// you could do the assignments as mentioned above.
```

Comment: crmprogdev, thank you for your response. I am still having the same issue. I created a new map<> and I am populating it like this: `ToUpdate.putAll(ToHoldValues)` and the DML outsitde the loop and is still saving the last checked value.

Comment: Unless you need to keep it in a map for other reasons, try just adding the records to a `list<Outbound_Sales_Order__c>`. After all, you're only updating the values in the map (not the Ids) and don't seem to be concerned with the wrapper class itself. Otherwise, you'd seem to need to keep a `map<id,list<Outbound_Sales_Order__c>>` from which to perform the update.

Comment: Hi crmprogdev, I tried using a list instead but I am getting an error Duplicates Ids in List. I would like to try this approach `map<id,list<Outbound_Sales_Order__c>>` but I don't know how to populate the map, could you please help me with this. I will truely appreciate it.

Comment: See my edited answer above. This is a much more complex problem to solve than is apparent on the surface.

Comment: crmprogdev, thank you so much! Now everything makes sense. I really appreciate it. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, Every time the query fetching the same Outbound_Sales_Order__c record.

Your selected 3 items in VF and cut the string every time. Resulted Name value is : 0049191. I strongly believe Name filed in every object takes unique value.So, In this case same record fetching 3 times

In the for loop you have added values to map. Map key doesn't allow duplicates. (3 same type of records having the same Id) That Y finally map contains the last record value (Last selected item in Vf).

Comment: Hi Vikas,  what do you recommend me to do in order to make this work? thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @Carlos Use  List<Outbound_Sales_Order__c> instead of Map<id,Outbound_Sales_Order__c> for updating.

Comment: Hi Vivas, I tried this approach but I am getting an error Duplicates Id in List

Comment: This was expected, Platform doesn't support to update the same record again and again using list at a time . If you want to update the same record again create new instance (Using SOQL) and do update(No List).    It seems your business logic not having scope to persist all bol(3) values in Bol_1__c field. Even though, If you will try my approach also, finally Bol_1__c field will have the selected item corresponding 'Bol' value.

Answer (score 1):

Try using list as given below :

```
public void CreatePlan() {
List<Outbound_Sales_Order__c> ToUpdate = new List<Outbound_Sales_Order__c>();

//here for loop to get values from wrap class 
for (String row : selectedTasks) 
{
    for(Outbound_Sales_Order__c p : [SELECT id  FROM Outbound_Sales_Order__c  WHERE  name =: row.substring(0,7)])
    {
        if(row.substring(21) == '1' ){ p.Bol_1__c = 'bol1';  }
        if(row.substring(21) == '2' ){ p.Bol_2__c = 'bol2';  }
        if(row.substring(21) == '3' ){ p.Bol_3__c = 'bol3';  }
        ToUpdate.add(p);
    }
    // if I do the update here, it will work.
}
//update outsite for loop 
UPDATE ToUpdate;
```

Comment: hi, I tried this approach but i am getting an error Duplicates Id in List .  Any ideas?

Comment: It's giving that error because it's getting same set of records each time it comes in 2nd for loop. Can you give some idea of what you are trying to achieve here?